# How to load a spring configuration from another dependency module

Tags: java, spring, junit4

I'm working on a spring application that contains submodules, roughly looking like the following:

project

```
|-- module1
||-- src
||      -- main
||       |-- java
||       -- resources
||           |-- null
||   -- pom.xml
```

Module 2:

```
|-- module2
|   |-- src
|   |   -- main
|   |       |-- java
|   |       -- resources
|   |           -- spring-dao.xml
|   -- pom.xml
-- pom.xml
```

now,I'm using Juit4 to test module1,while I have to offer `spring-dao.xml` in module1,like this:
`@ContextConfiguration({"classpath*:spring/spring-dao.xml"})`

But the spring configuration file(`spring-dao.xml`) is in module2, and module2 is dependent on module1. That causes I can't put module2.jar into module1 via the pom.xml of module1 as it causes a module cycle.

How can I test module1?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand completely, but here's how I read it:

Module 1 has a dependency on Module 2, and Module 2 has a dependency on Module 1.

The short answer is you cannot do this. The idea behind modules is to segregate unrelated code. I often do this with generated code, keeping that in a separate module. The generated code shouldn't have any dependencies on my main application, but my main application depends on the generated code.

I can think of a couple solutions:

If the two modules are that heavily dependent on each other, they should be refactored into a single module. This seems like the best approach, based on what you've described.

If this still isn't desireable, make a third module to hold common dependencies between the two projects.

Comment: U understand correctly.The short question is that the module2 has a dependent on module1 in project (The module1 doesn't dependency on module2). Then I need to unit test module1, but I must provide the configure.xml file belongs to module2 to module1 in order to complete unit test. A thrid module mabey is a solution.But I just need a configure.xml file,whether there is a lightweight way to sovle this problem.

Comment: If it's only a single file used for testing and only testing, creating a test specific configuration file would solve the problem.